# Multi-Processing with Sub-process, Python, and PSQL

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess, psql

I have 100 locations that I am trying to process. Each location requires the same workflow, so I have developed a set of scripts to do so.

First, I do some prep of the location files in Python. This 1st Python code then calls another (2nd) Python script using Sub-Process. This second Python calls modules and executes some routines before calling Sub-Process again to run a bunch of PSQL commands.

Once the first Python script calls the second, it is free to start on the next location. Right now, I am allowing 5 instances of the second Python to be triggered:

```
for x, every in enumerate(location):
   .... (PREP CODE)
   if x == 0:
      process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
   elif x == 1:
      process1 = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
   elif x == 2:
      process2 = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
   elif x == 3:
      process3 = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
   elif x == 4:
      process4 = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)

while process.poll() is None:
    time.sleep(0.5)
while process1.poll() is None:
    time.sleep(0.5)
while process2.poll() is None:
    time.sleep(0.5)
while process3.poll() is None:
    time.sleep(0.5)
while process4.poll() is None:
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

I don't use PIPE or stdout as it appears to lock up successive calls of sub-process. Inside the second python I do a bunch of processing and then call:

```
def execute_psql(code):
    command = 'psql -f %s "host=postgres.local dbname=projects user=david password=XXXXX port=5432"' % (codespace + '\\codes\\' + str(i) + code + '.sql')
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
    while process.poll() is None:
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

This is called about 15 times due to the number of individual PSQL scripts that I have to run.

When I run this set of codes on 1 location it runs and completes successfully in 3 hours. When I run with even just 2 locations, time increases dramatically and I would venture to say stops for most of the processes. Right now I am testing 2 at a time. 30% of PSQL scripts were executed successfully for 1 location and 90% for the other. The current PSQL have been running for 6 and 20 hours respectively.

What can be causing the code to just stall like this? I am in the midst of testing theories (e.g. (1) change shell=True to shell= False ; e.g.(2) rename all variables including "process" to be a unique variable name).

On the database side: The code that is up to 20 hours is only reading (with htop status = R) and is using up 100% of the CPU on one core. The 6 hour code is at 3% CPU usage and is in status D (or uninterruptible sleep).

Comment: This is quite convoluted way of doing things, but if I understand correctly you are basically only starting few python processes and then wait for a long time for the (2*15?) `psql` commands to end? In that case the issue is with the database queries, not python.

Comment: I'm not very proficient with multi-threading yet. Just getting my feet wet. When each PSQL code is run independently in PG ADMIN, each executes successfully.

Comment: sounds like a job that might be better suited to shell scripting.  GNU `parallel` might be useful for running the database tasks.  otherwise, you could try using the `multiprocessing` module rather than trying to do your own thing with `exec`ing other Python interpreters

Comment: Just to clarify, this is not multi-threading. Multiple processes do not share the same memory space, multiple threads share the same memory space. I am mainly confused why you need to have an indirection starting another python subprocess which then starts `psql` instances. You can do all that in the original python process. Also you really should use a list to store all your subprocesses that you created to avoid all that code repetition. Use `.wait()` or `.communicate()` instead of a `poll` loop.

Comment: And still I don't know which of the processes it is that is doing work and you are waiting on. It would be much easier to understand with some `top` output or similar. I still think that this is a database issue. Have you tested the exact same commands that you create in `execute_psql` on the command line and in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

Parallelization is hard to get right. If the order of the locations does not matter it may be easier to make a single threaded program that processes one location and then parallelize this using an external tool - such as GNU Parallel:

```
parallel python process_one_location.py ::: location1 location2 location3 .. locationN
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot.